# Converting a generic function argument to an `Arc` with a generic trait

Tags: generics, rust, higher-kinded-types

Is it possible to have a function with a generic argument that converts that argument to an `Arc` with a generic trait? Something like this:

```rust
struct Foo<TypeOrTrait> {
    arc: Option<Arc<TypeOrTrait>>,
}

impl<TypeOrTrait> Foo<TypeOrTrait> {
    fn set<T>(&mut self, t: T) -> Arc<T> {
        let arc = Arc::new(t);
        self.arc = Some(arc.clone()); // Error
        arc
    }
}
```

The code complains that it can't convert `Arc<T>` to `Arc<TypeOrTrait>`.

In my code I don't have just the `Arc` that wraps `TypeOrTrait`, but a complex `Arc<RwLock<Inner<TypeOrTrait>>>` so I can't work around this by passing `Arc<TypeOrTrait>` to the `set` function.

The use case I have is that I want to have a collection that only implements a trait, but also want to have a way to access/modify the values using their original types. Something like this:

```rust
let foo: Foo<fmt::Display> = Foo { arc: None };

let value = foo.set(1u8);
assert_eq!(*value, 1u8);
assert_eq!(foo.bar.unwrap().to_string(), "1");

let value = foo.set(2u16);
assert_eq!(*value, 2u16);
assert_eq!(foo.bar.unwrap().to_string(), "2");
```

I was told that this would require higher kinded types, is that correct? If so, could it be emulated with something like what they do [here](https://gist.github.com/edmundsmith/855fcf0cb35dd467c29a9350481f0ecf) (my Rust fu isn't on a par with that)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only few traits and types, you can use a custom trait:

```rust
pub trait ConvertArc<To: ?Sized> {
    fn convert(self: Arc<Self>) -> Arc<To>;
}

impl<T: ?Sized> ConvertArc<T> for T {
    fn convert(self: Arc<Self>) -> Arc<Self> { self }
}
impl ConvertArc<dyn Trait> for Struct {
    fn convert(self: Arc<Self>) -> Arc<dyn Trait> { self }
}

struct S<TypeOrTrait: ?Sized> {
    arc: Option<Arc<TypeOrTrait>>,
}

impl<TypeOrTrait: ?Sized> S<TypeOrTrait> {
    fn set<T: ConvertArc<TypeOrTrait>>(&mut self, t: T) -> Arc<T> {
        let arc = Arc::new(t);
        self.arc = Some(arc.clone().convert());
        arc
    }
}
```

If you have many traits or types... well... I think you don't have a solution. You can almost use [`std::marker::Unsize`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Unsize.html) on nightly, but not, because you want to be able to use the same type for both too.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm having trouble compiling this code, please see [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c55145bc3068f98200f6cb19489679cb) for details.

Comment: @PeterJankuliak This is not a complete listing, it misses `Trait` and `Struct`. This is just an example of how to have the trait and how to implement it for the traits and structs you have.

Comment: I see, thanks. My attempt here is to extract a pattern that we use in multiple places in our code so it can be better analyzed, tested and reused so unfortunately it is the case that I have many traits and types. Actually most of the time the `T` and `TypeOrTrait` are the same type, it's just one special case where I need `TypeOrTrait` to be `Display + Sync + Send`. Would you know if the statement that it would be possible with higher kinded types is true? If so, would you know how it could be implemented with it?

Comment: @PeterJankuliak I edited the answer. If most usages are the same type, you can have one blanket implementation for all cases where it's the same type. And I don't understand how you got HKT here, it is not related at all.

Comment: Yes, [this works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d155cd7a10533277a5b08229724578bc) and it's an OK solution as I only need to write the `ConvertArc` in a small number of cases. Thanks.